# MC95 - Loading camera throws Can't find PInvoke DLL 'EMDKServices.dll' error

Tags: c#, motorola-emdk

I'm developing a .net application on a Motorola MC95 scanner and when trying to turn on the camera I am getting this error: Can't find PInvoke DLL 'EMDKServices.dll'. I have received this error before but it was always if the scanner was already enabled.  I'm running the same code on 4 scanners and can only reproduce the issue on two of them. Unfortunately the two scanners that we can reproduce the issue with are a few thousand miles from me.

**What would be possible causes for receiving the error: Can't find PInvoke DLL 'EMDKServices.dll'. When enabling the camera?**

I've had them try the default demo app and it loads and takes a picture without issue.

Using EMDK for .Net version 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual cause for this was that the scanner that was throwing the error was missing the 'Symbol Managed Class Libraries' application. It was determined that when deploying directly from visual studio to the scanner it automatically pushes and installs this application, but when deploying via a cab installer it does not get installed. The fix was to add a check to the application startup to see if the libraries were installed and throw an error to the user.

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"\Windows\AppMgr\Symbol Managed Class Libraries\") == false)
{
    DisplayMessage("Symbol Managed Class Libraries not detected. Please Install or contact help desk.", "Error");
}
```

To install the libraries run the following cab on the device:
Get the cab from a computer that has the EMDK installed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Motorola EMDK for .NET\v2.8\SDK\Smart Devices\wce500\armv4i\symbol.all.arm.cab
Once this is run and installed on the device the camera works perfectly.

I investigated for a way to include this cab in my cab but didn't find a clean way to do it without doing a lot of after work after every build. Considering it's a one time run per device I am fine with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

when using PInvoke, the system following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) to search for the native DLLs. By default, the Standard Search Order for Desktop Applications is:

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the
   path of this directory.
3. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the
   path of this directory, but it is searched.
4. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get
   the path of this directory. The current directory.
5. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.
   Note that this does not include the per-application path specified
   by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when
   computing the DLL search path.

As to your problem, you can use the tool [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor your process, it call log the file activities of the process, which will show you how the process searches for a certain DLL.

As you said, your program works on some machines, some not. By compare the logs of process monitor, you should be able to find what is wrong.